# Cropping to the Shortest Image Height in a Single Row of Images?

Tags: html, css, image, grid, row

Is it possible to crop images to the shortest height of an image in a single row of images? If so, can this be done solely with CSS?

Here is an example of what I'd like to accomplish:

[image]

And here is the code I am currently working on:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row .item {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.row img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/708bb6dcdaf359fd2ea83d11a0b5b4b8/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco3_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c49ef0b40483c35ad3b6898c0e037e11/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco2_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/737456a69c07da1a9a2784506f62dce9/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco9_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solutions or advice?

Comment: you need javascript or jquery to define the min height

Comment: @M0ns1f Thanks, what type of function would I need to achieve this?

Comment: You could with css if you were able to know the min width and height

Comment: Mainly the height of the smallest size

Comment: @Jonny Thanks, but that's the main concern. The height of the shortest image is indeterminable as it will vary, for responsive purposes...

Comment: You will need Javascript or JQuery to do this without fixed measurements as @M0ns1f mentioned.

Comment: @Jonny Ok. I am looking for a point to start, any resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to use JS for this, unless you can process the heights on a backend script and set a height on the container as it is output.

Anyways, here is a little bit of JS that should achieve what you want:

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const row = document.querySelector('.row');

function normalizeImages(images, container) {
  const shortestItem = images.reduce((smallest, element) => {
    return element.clientHeight < smallest.clientHeight ? element : smallest;
  });

  container.style.height = `${shortestItem.clientHeight}px`;
}

normalizeImages(items, row);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => normalizeImages(items, row));
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row .item {
  flex-basis: 33.33333%;
}

.row img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/708bb6dcdaf359fd2ea83d11a0b5b4b8/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco3_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c49ef0b40483c35ad3b6898c0e037e11/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco2_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/737456a69c07da1a9a2784506f62dce9/tumblr_oyslstg5xk1unhdoco9_r1_1280.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that a small amount of CSS has changed to hide overflow on the .row element

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution works if the screen width size is static. Is there any way this function can work responsively, such as when a screen width increases or decreases?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code to show an example of how you could fire the resize when the window resizes. If you're doing this on a lot of images/rows you'll probably want to integrate some event throttling on the resize event so it down't slow your page down on resize.